# Shopify moveable section: can it be edited in the customiser while sharing the same data across the site?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to make a Shopify section for multiple pages of my site. I want the section to be moveable up and down each page. I want the section to contain the same data across the site, so it only has to be input once from the customiser.

I currently can't see how this is possible with Sections Everywhere. Is this possible? Any tutorials?

Thanks

I can create static sections and I can create dynamic sections. I want an in between

Comment: An example would be a banner with "We planted 500 trees". I want this banner to be on multiple pages and I want to be able to update the number of trees through customiser. The banner is sometimes at the top of the page, sometimes at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using static sections, not dynamic ones. However, you won't be able to move them freely.

Check my answer on similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73986078/6110804